# Can you touch up to six objects as a full round action when casting a touch spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, touch-attacks

> You can touch one friend as a standard action or up to six friends as a full-round action.

So states the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#Touch_Spells_in_Combat). But let's say you were to cast a spell that's designed to be cast on a touched object, like, say, Obscure Object? Could you touch up to six objects in one turn as a full round action?

Comment: Well, Obscure Object specifically targets *one* object, not sure if there are spells affecting several objects with a range of touch

Comment: Plenty of spells not specifically targeted on objects can still affect them. This question would be quite relevant when seeing, for example, how many technical manuals your extremist-technophobe druid character could burn with her Flame Blade before the spell duration ran out. (Or how many the villainous extremist technophobe can get destroyed in the N rounds it takes the PCs to get there and stop her.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Possibly, but most of the time it won't cause an additional effect**
Even if you inferred or house ruled that the rules for touching willing creatures for the purposes of spell targeting also applied to touching inanimate objects, none of them would be affected unless the spell already allowed multiple target objects.

The key limitation is the spell targeting clauses, not the number of objects you can touch in a round. The "up to six friends" limit only applies to spells that specifically affect more than one touched target. *[Obscure object](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/obscureObject.html)*, *[teleport object](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/teleportObject.html)*, and similar spells that specifically say **one touched object**, and thus don't qualify. The spell effect will discharge when you first touch an object, and everything after the first will not be affected even if you can touch it in the same round. If you wanted to affect a second object with a single target spell, you'd need to cast another spell.